# Which design is better: provide direct access to an owned object or give owning object forwarding methods to the owned object?

Tags: c++, oop

Which is better:

```
class Owner
{
public:
    void SomeMethodA()
    {
        _ownee.SomeMethodA();
    }

    int SomeMethodB()
    {
        return _ownee.SomeMethodB();
    }

private:
    Ownee _ownee;
};
```

or this:

```
class Ownee
{
public:
    void SomeMethodA();
    int SomeMethodB();
};

class Owner
{
public:
    Ownee& GetOwnee() const
    {
        return _ownee;
    }

private:
    Ownee _ownee;
};
```

I seem to recall reading long ago that the first option is better than the second option, but I can't remember why.  I want to say because there is less coupling between users of Owner and Ownee.  Clients would only need to know about Owner's interface and not Ownee's whereas with the second option clients would need to be aware of both Owner's and Ownee's interfaces.

Comment: second one must be using less memory. 1 ownee for many owners

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: Definitely not.  Each owner certainly has it's own instance of the ownee.

Comment: Either should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

One's not superior in every regard, in every case. However, wrapping the interfaces and encapsulating the members (the first one) is *generally* preferable.

A class and its members have special relationships. A class often uses its interface to restrict functionality to operate within the domain it is intended, and it may be used to for additional internal state validation and to improve program correctness.

When well encapsulated, the `Owner` has far more freedom to change its implementation or members as needed.

Exposing members can often lead to higher coupling, and ultimately push a lot of long term maintenance onto the client (resulting in more bugs, and redundant implementations for the client). A rather obvious example of this: assume the `Owner` has two members, and thread safety must be guaranteed -- it makes little sense to push that responsibility onto the clients, and to expect the clients to implement and maintain thread safety over several changes over several years. However, the `Owner` can abstract all that, and alter its implementation appropriately when its implementation changes, or prevent changes to members (`Ownee`) from affecting clients in this regard.

Changes to the classes (either `Owner` or `Ownee`) will generally affect the client far less when its members are not exposed, and the class (`Owner`) provides a strict, simple interface to its functionalities.

'Performance' is often regarded as a reason to *favor* the second ("Just provide clients accessors"). I find that an unfounded over-simplification. Performance may be better or it may worse! It depends on many, many things in C++ when developing nontrivial programs. Again, using the locking example: a bad interface of the first and/or favoring public accessors can require far more locking. As well, the optimizer has locality of the information and its members. There may be a good amount of internal implementation and methods provided by `Owner` -- if that's largely private, and uses static dispatch, it can result in a very small set of exported (or inline, if you favor) methods. An accessor in itself may not be so bad, but operations and dependencies on the accessed may push a lot of instructions and dependencies out to your clients -- when your internal implementation of `Owner` may represent all that in a single, compact, optimized form. In C++, abstraction layers can be very cheap (often nothing if done well) when optimized. Performance swings both ways here in the real world, and depends on many variables.

Most often, I use the first form. When I use the second form, it's often with:

- Private/Inner classes.
- or as components of a larger system (e.g. meta-programming).

Reads:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Of_Demeter

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding

Comment: On the other hand, I've seen several libraries that use the first method providing classes with an unending list of methods just because they have to wrap almost any method of their owned objects, sometimes with subtle but important variations in parameters, .... This leads to a cluttered interface and imposes you to commit to memory both the interface of the owned object (that you already use on its own in other parts of your project) and this wrapping interface.

Comment: @MatteoItalia +1 i certainly agree that what you describe happens in the real world. such 'abstractions' can and should often be either redesigned and/or simplified. what you describe is typical of leaky abstractions and/or abstraction inversion -- from wrapping without much consideration for design. although, some complex implementations can be simplified only so much, until they fail to provide necessary functionalities when representing complex programs.

Comment: that's exactly what I think about the libraries I refer to. Although, I think that for CERN's ROOT (the library I was thinking about when writing that comment) a simple redesign is definitely not enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of the Pimpl (pointer to implementation) idiom.

One nice way to do this is to declare the implementation class in the header file and define it in the .c file; this ensures that no one can see the details via .h inclusion.

## .h file

```
#ifndef object_INCLUDED
#define object_INCLUDED

#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

class Object
{
public:
    //...
private:

    class ObjectImpl;
    boost::scoped_ptr<ObjectImpl> impl_;
}

#endif
```

## .c file

```
#include "object.h"

//==================================================
// Implementation of ObjectImpl
//==================================================

class Object::ObjectImpl
{

public:

    ObjectImpl(int);
    int value() const;

private:

    int val_;
};

Object::ObjectImpl::ObjectImpl(int val)
    : val_(val)
{}

int
Object::ObjectImpl::value() const
{
    return val_;
}

//==================================================
// Implementation of Object
//==================================================

Object::Object(int val)
    : impl_(new ObjectImpl(val))
{
}
```